# curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: 14.04, ssl, amazon-ec2, curl

**Edit:**
I had updated my root CA certificates from curl.haxx.se .

---

When I try `curl -Iv https://yahoo.com` I get an error as `unable to get local issuer certificate` in the result. However if I try `curl -Iv --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt https://yahoo.com` I get a result without any error.

Weirdly `curl -Iv https://google.com` works properly. But `curl -Iv https://deb.nodesource.com` doesn't.

Is there any chance to overcome this issue? (by changing curl configuration etc.)

```
root@ip-172-31-40-176:/var# curl -Iv https://yahoo.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://yahoo.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 206.190.36.45...
* Connected to yahoo.com (206.190.36.45) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Answer (score 6):

Becase curl is unable to verify the certificate provided by the server.

There are two way to bypass:

1.add `-k` option which allows curl to make insecure connections, which does not verify the certificate.

2.add root curl ca ([download here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)) to `/etc/ssl/certs/nodesource-ca.crt`

Comment: So, why does curl work with Google.com?

Comment: @user3765109 Oh, just a mistake. It's curl's ca missing, I have update the answer.

Comment: No worry. Because I had to edit my question too :) Actually, I've set up the new server because of this issue. It had taken my 2 days! :)  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Or, for me, worked simply this:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Said the `ca-certificates is already the newest version`. Still having SSL cert problems.